# How common is it to find a true baritone?

Tags: vocal-range

Most men I tried to sing with often sung lower than `C3`. I am a *tenor* and I find this too low.

This made me think that most men are *baritones* but...it could be that they are, in fact, not true baritones.

How common is it to find a *true* baritone?

Comment: This is similar to [your other question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74870/is-it-real-vocal-science-to-say-that-most-men-can-sing-a2?rq=1).

Comment: @Théophile IMO, close but no cigar.

Comment: Hank, do you mean among singers? Among all humans? All males? What's your population for this research?